# Dual package statements in Scala

Tags: scala, package

I have seen in a few libraries, Spray for example, dual package specifications like this:

```
package cc.spray
package http

// code
```

Is this just eye candy for package cc.spray.http, or is there a functional benefit to breaking the two apart like this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is equivalent to this:

```
package cc.spray.http
import cc.spray._
// implicitly, import cc.spray.http._
```

That is, every member of package `cc.spray` and of package `cc.spray.http` are visible. On the other hand, members of the package `cc` are *not* visible.

This way one can safely use names such as `java` in their package hierarchy without causing trouble, and, at the same time, easily make visible the package scopes one wants to be visible.

Comment: Just when you think you start to know a language, something know and cool shows up...

Answer (score 3):

The separate package statements puts both `cc.spray` and `cc.spray.http` in scope.

Answer (score 1):

let's not forget one nice win gained from this approach

```
// Foo.scala
package cc.spray
package http

class Foo {
  ...
}

// Bar.Scala
package cc.spray
package bar

import http._ // concise imports relative to cc.spray

class Bar {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like a lot of other things, this was introduced with Scala 2.8: the other answers give you the "what" (exposing multiple package scopes to the current context) and the official Scala doc has [a lot more detail](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/package-clauses/packageclauses.html), along with a detailed rationale for the feature.